# How to decrease wasm smart contract deployment fee without decreasing Transaction fee?

Tags: substrate-node-template, smart-contract, pallet-contracts

i am using substrate `pallet_contracts` for wasm contract deployment how can i set the fees for contract deployment?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas i want to decrease the contract deployment fees on my chain,currently if i deploy an erc721 wasm contract it costs around (6 tokens) i want to decrease this amount how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust `DepositPerItem` and `DepositPerByte` in the `pallet-contracts` configuration.

You can take a look at how this is configured in Substrate (do not use these values as they are likely unsuitable for something that has economic value). Here is the link to the configuration file: [GitHub - Substrate runtime configuration](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1216-L1241).

If you are deploying to a solo chain that has different hardware specifications than Polkadot, you should probably run the weight benchmark against hardware that matches the specifications of your network. This thread might be helpful for that: [Stack Exchange - How to generate WeightInfo for pallets](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/295/how-to-generate-weightinfo-for-pallets).